# Multithreading issue : I want add an extra thread to write and save that 4 threads that already read from 4 text files in a new text file

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, python-multithreading

I have 4 threads reading from 4 text files and print it on the screen. I want to make extra thread to write & save that 4 threads read in a new text file.
**Current Code:**

```
import pandas as pd
import threading
from datetime import datetime 

start_time = datetime.now() 


def print_text(filename):
    text = pd.read_csv(filename, delimiter = "\t")
    print(text)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    filenames = ['file1.txt', "file2.txt", "file3.txt", "file4.txt"]
    
    
    # Create thread for each filename.
    threads = [threading.Thread(target=print_text, args=(filename,)) for filename in filenames]

    # Start execution of each thread.
    for thread in threads:
        thread.start()
    
    # Join threads when execution is complete.
    for thread in threads:
        thread.join()
        
time_elapsed = datetime.now() - start_time 

print('Time elapsed (hh:mm:ss.ms) {}'.format(time_elapsed))
```

Comment: Could you clarify what you want this additional thread to do, and why this additional thread is necessary?

Comment: @BrokenBenchmark
the additional thread takes the reading result from 4 threads and save it in a new text file.
Its important because I compare of execution time between 3 cases and this the last case.

Comment: Your four threads are not producing any results.  They just print to the screen and return `None`.  There's nothing for an additional thread to grab.  You could create a `queue.Queue`, then have your four threads write each line to the queue, and have your 5th thread read from the queue and print it, but what you have won't work.

Comment: @TimRoberts the mean point of this case is taking that 4 threads printing to the screen and save it into new text file by 5th thread. 
sorry to say "reading result" this is not accurate and miscommunication from me.

Comment: I understand exactly.  You say "save it into new text file", but there is nothing to save.  The threads copy their file to the console.  They produce no results.  There is nothing for the 5th thread to save.

Comment: I would also point out that `pd.read_csv` does not produce text.  It produces a DataFrame object.  I do not see a purpose to this exercise.

Comment: @TimRoberts yes I agree with you for Pandas is not the best option here to use.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240646/discussion-between-ali-elmesawy-and-tim-roberts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This shows how to use a queue to route the output of your four "writer" threads to a "reader" thread.  The astute reader will realize that there is no point in spawning a 5th thread for this.  We could call `print_result` in the mainline code and get the same result with lower overhead.

```
import queue
import threading
from datetime import datetime 

start_time = datetime.now() 

def print_text(q, filename):
    for line in open(filename):
        q.put(line.strip())
    q.put('--end--')

def print_result(q, count=0):
    while count:
        line = q.get()
        if line == '--end--':
            count -= 1
        else:
            print(line)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    filenames = ['file1.txt', "file2.txt", "file3.txt", "file4.txt"]
    q = queue.Queue()    
    threads = [threading.Thread(target=print_text, args=(q, filename)) for filename in filenames]
    threads.append( threading.Thread(target=print_result, args=(q, len(filenames))) )

    # Start execution of each thread.
    for thread in threads:
        thread.start()
    
    # Join threads when execution is complete.
    for thread in threads:
        thread.join()
        
time_elapsed = datetime.now() - start_time 

print('Time elapsed (hh:mm:ss.ms) {}'.format(time_elapsed))
```